# Apache VirtualHost Preventing Tomcat Connection

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, virtualhost

Apache VirtualHost appears to prevent call to Tomcat.

I am attempting to setup configuration that will provide this result:

- http://example.com/examples -- call Tomcat
- http://example.com/examples/* -- call Tomcat
- http://example.com/examples2 -- call Tomcat
- http://example.com/examples2/* -- call Tomcat
- http://example.com/AnythingElse -- call Apache

Server is Unix OmniOS (child of Open Solaris & Open BSD)
Installed Apache 2.4.38
Installed Tomcat 8.5.32
Installed jk 1.2.43

Apache is listening on two ports

- https://localhost:80
- https://localhost:8888

Confirmed that Tomcat is running and JK connection is working when calling either of the Apache listing ports

I then install the Apache VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/cgi-bin/example.com"
   ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now call to `http://example.com/examples` returns `404` not found instead of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
I just needed to add my JkMount entries inside my VirtualHost as well.